RSU example scenario results analysis
I'm new here and hoping I could get help with my research.
I have adjusted the RSU example scenario to fit my scenario. Still, after analyzing the data from the statistic filter, I found so many matrixes such as maxspeed, CO2 emission, sent packets, received broadcast, busy time, etc.
So my question is, how do I know the parameters for these matrixes and how to quantify them in real-life scenarios, and also know if the data is the average of all vehicles and rsu?
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me or point me to a paper or articles on this.
Thank you.
How can I verify the data parameter in the statistic filter in omntepp results?
